# How do I set a default checked option with Rails collection_radio_buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to set the first radio button as checked by default for a form. I can't figure out how to do it. I can get all of the inputs to have `checked="checked"` by adding checked: true or checked: 'checked' in the html options, as in the following:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, {}, { checked: true } %>
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, {}, { checked: 'checked' } %>
```

I've tried specifying checked: `@category.first`, as in the following:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, {}, { checked: @category.first } %>
```

But that doesn't work either. None of the inputs are checked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should marked `id` to be checked, so change to `{ checked: @category.first.id }`

Comment: This is correct. You can look at the documentation for further reference and sample uses: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons

Comment: That worked! Although, I had to put in the options hash, and not the html_options hash (which is where I had it before).

Comment: Thanks - was struggling with this for a while.

Comment: This works but it overrides the selected value stored in the database in edit form for an existing entity..

Answer (score 3):

For me works writing that in the first branches {}, in this way:

```
form.collection_radio_buttons(:category_id, @categories, :id, :name, { checked: @categories.first.id }, { class: "category-options"})
```

Comment: I also had to use it this way